# On definition of differentiable function for functions of several variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

The definition of differentiable that I have in my notebook is:

$f:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ is differentiable in $x$ if exist $a \in \mathbb{R}^n $ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+(a,y)+o(y)$, for all $y$.

My questions are:

1. What mean $(a, y)$?
2. What mean $o(y)$?

Thanks to all.

Comment: $(a,y)$ means the inner product (dot product) of $a$ with $y$, and $o(y)$ means little-oh of $y$, that is, a function $g(y)$ such that $g(y)/y\to0$ as $y\to0$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic, you know about a book where I can see this definition? Because in all book I see others definitions (with linear aplication). Thanks for you help.

Comment: Every linear application $L:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is in the form of $(a,y)$, an inner product against an element $a$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks, @WillieWong

Comment: @symplectomorphic I guess you mean $g(y)/\Vert y\Vert$, since $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro: whoops, yes; the notation should be $o(\|y\|)$, not $o(y)$.

Comment: In my definition (differentiable) is $o(y)$ or $o(\|y\|)$?